# Changed ESLint, React errors no longer show in browser

Tags: reactjs, compiler-errors, eslint

I'm working on a project with multiple people, and we changed our ESLint a bit. If there were React/ ESLint errors, it would fail to compile and show the errors in the browser.

The project was made using CRA a few years ago and is still on React 17

**The problem:** Since changing, all the errors go to the Problems tab and the browser just freezes. Also, the errors appear in the dev tools. It's almost like the errors are just going to the wrong spot. I'd really like the errors to also appear in the browser.

Here is my .eslintrc.js: Any ideas?

```
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
    es6: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: ['airbnb', 'prettier'],
  overrides: [],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 12,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  ignorePatterns: ['src/assets/js/*.js', 'node_modules/*'],
  plugins: ['react', 'prettier'],
  rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': ['error'],
    'react/prop-types': 'off',
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': [1, { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'] }],
    camelcase: 'off',
    'jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions': 'off',
    'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': 'off',
    'default-param-last': 'off',
  },
};
```

It could be some local error unrelated to ESLint, but I just changed that and a few dependencies.

`package.json`

```
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.11",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
```

Thank you, I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: Try with the command  `npm i eslint-webpack-plugin@2.4.3 --save-dev -E`

Comment: @krupalimakadiya thank you so much for responding! I tried your command, did a few restarts and installs to check. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to change anything. Errors go to the terminal/problems and the browser freezes until the problems are resolved.

Comment: Try cleaning the node_modules and then cache clean fresh install the node_modules sometimes due to cache also it's not working

Comment: @krupalimakadiya, thank you for your suggestion. I've been doing that every time and it hasn't changed anything.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I deleted our `package-lock.json` at some point when doing a new `npm install` and somehow that caused this error. I thought it was typically okay to delete lock files, but after I added it back and did a fresh install it all seems okay now.